# Why is only consol.log working?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript

I successfully added a JS file to my page and every **console.log** is working okay. Unfortunately no other function is working.

This is how my file looks like.

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "domReady!"
], function($){

  $(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('does it work?');

    if(1 == 1) {
      console.log("true");
    } else {
      console.log("false");
    };

  });

});
```

And it **doesn't work** as well - no output. Does anybody has an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: RequireJs doesn't execute until after the DOM is loaded, so you need to remove the `ready`  event.

Comment: But how is it possible that the first console log is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code lines should work. However, make sure that this file is in **static content** also. 
If we change only on our module, our function may not work. Magento will load js files from `pub/static` content folder, not from your module (under `app` folder).

There is a way to debug and check our js: we can check the Sources in Browser. Make sure your new change is in this file. We can disable Browser Cache for testing purpose.

[image]

From my experience, we can edit the js file directly in static content folder. If our function can work, we will copy it to our "real" js file in module or theme.

Comment: You can also add the `debugger;` keyword to your code. When you then surf in chrome or firefox with the developper tools open the execution of the javascript wil stop at that breakpoint.
More info: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: @AndrejZemplényi you're right, your code lines should work.

Comment: So this actually helped me to find the root of the problem. My JS actually works but it seems like just a few of jQuery functions or any JS applies. For example .hide() doesn't work on any element but changing it by .html() it produces some results (But only on aside element)... However my point is to select an input and do some stuff with it. But selecting an input by $("input[name='company']"); doesn't work neither does work selecting parent div or mostly any other div. What could be the case? Is it beceuse of the AJAX that is loading that it doesn't find it? Thanks for help

Comment: @AndrejZemplényi you should open new question. I will take a look at the new issue.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150957/checkout-page-javascript-cant-target-inputs here's the link. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrejZemplényi I see your new question. However, if my answer here can solve your question above, please accept it as a solution.