# Checkout Page - JavaScript can't target inputs

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

On my checkout page I'd like to do some JavaScript on Inputs and other elements.

It seems like I can't access certain part of my page. To verify i tried $("form").html("these forms I could find");

[image: description of problems]

I use extension by IWD Agency, but I believe this has nothing to do with their module.

When editing JS inside module you can see that only Search bar and Payment Selection could be change, other forms remain unchanged.

When editing JS from my custom module I can change only Search Bar.

I guess this is caused by AJAX that forms are not loaded when the script runs. Any ideas how could this be changed?

Thank you!

Comment: You should read more here: https://inviqa.com/blog/technical-guide-magento-2-checkout

Comment: This didn't really help, since they are using  KO javascript, I'd like to just add simple jquery to toggle inputs and do some interaction with shipping methods. But still, the JS works but is not applied to checkout form since it appears a bit later on the page. And again the weird part was that it affected payment options but nothing else.

Comment: Magento 2 used Knockout and Json Object template for rendering the One Page Checkout. For binding event, Knockout uses its own binding syntax- data-bind- to bind the event to the element. So, we need to add the custom event via data-bind.

Comment: Or, we can override the existing js component. The Js component used for rendering the template.

Comment: I'm a real beginner with KO. Is there any way to bind certain function to parent DIV? In link you posted they refer to XML file which I would like not to edit for this purpose.

Comment: In the XML, we can see some `JS component`? `JS component` is important. It can define the template. You need to find which Js component contains your html template.

Comment: So actually I don't really know if what I'm trying makes any sense. I tried to include my module inside the checkout_index_index.xml i tried to bind in requirejs-config.js to #checkout div but still no success. When injecting my JS to scripts of the module it can affect only payment methods.  http://pastebin.com/xFhr27bx this is how the xml looks like.

Comment: Which Js file you tried to edit? What did you do in `requirejs-config.js`?

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220331/46716