# Load a jQuery script after fully loading the page

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery

I'm struggeling with this. My jQuery script works fin with every of my input, but not with the input loaded by AJAX, such as the mini-cart input.

The code (and the css) is used to do this : add to each input of quantity to right a + and - to have a better UI, instead of the small default arrows.

See my code :

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "bootstrap",
    ],
    function($)
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log(" ====== main.js is loaded====== ");

        $(document).ready(function()
        {                
            $('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter('.quantity input');
            $('.quantity').each(function() {
                                btnUp.on("click", function() {
                console.log("up");
                let newVal;
                let oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
                if (oldValue >= max) {
                    newVal = oldValue;
                } else {
                    newVal = oldValue + 1;
                }
                spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
                spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
            });

            btnDown.on("click", function() {
                console.log("down");
                let newVal;
                let oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
                if (oldValue <= min) {
                    newVal = oldValue;
                } else {
                    newVal = oldValue - 1;
                }
                spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
                spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
            });

            });
        });
    });
```

I tried thing like live, ajaxComplete, ready, even add the code into the default.html part of the checkout minicart.

But the script is not working with ajax loaded content. What should I do ?

Comment: Instead of `$(document).ready(function()` you should use `$(window).load(function()`

Comment: Tried already, not working

Comment: Hello, You can check out this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220323/how-to-add-a-js-script-after-full-loading-checkout-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "bootstrap",
    ],
    function($)
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log(" ====== main.js is loaded====== ");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter('.quantity input');

            $(document).on('click', '.quantity-button.quantity-up', function(event) {
                alert('up button clicked');
                // your custom code
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.quantity-button.quantity-down', function(event) {
                alert('down button clicked');
                // your custom code
            });
        });
    }
);
```

replace ".quantity-button.quantity-up" with your actual class name anything else.

If you define this way, it will work even after content is loaded by ajax.

Hope this helps.