# How to add a JS script after full page loading in checkout in magento2?

Tags: knockoutjs, magento-2.2.5, checkout-page, loader

Since the checkout page is loaded asynchronously, I am not able to call the js script after entire page is loaded.I tried using below code

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            if($('#checkout-loader').length == 0)
            {   
                alert("Completed Loading");
            }    
        })

    })
```

But the above code is called twice after loader is remove.Please suggest me how can i implement after all the elements are loaded

Comment: check this --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220323/how-to-add-a-js-script-after-full-loading-checkout-page?rq=1

Comment: Let me know how to implement below code as per suggested link
 hideLoader: function() {
          //your code here
            },